# Piped Streaming with Netty

Tags: java, stream, netty, nio

I'm trying to implement a "thumbnail generator" as a microservice. I think such a thing probably works best as a TCP server and so after briefly surveying a few options I settled on Netty. In order to make the service as memory-efficient as possible I would prefer to avoid ever loading the full image into memory and therefore have been trying to build a pipeline whose "ThumbnailHandler" can use piped streams to take advantage of Netty's chunked reading so that as Netty receives more bytes, the thumbnail generator can traverse more of the stream. Unfortunately I'm not familiar enough with Netty or NIO patterns in general to know if I'm going about this the best way and I'm having trouble getting even a simplified version to work like I'd expect.

Here's my server setup:

```
public class ThumbnailerServer {

    private int port;

    public ThumbnailerServer(int port) {
        this.port = port;
    }

    public void run() throws Exception {
        final ThreadFactory acceptFactory = new DefaultThreadFactory("accept");
        final ThreadFactory connectFactory = new DefaultThreadFactory("connect");
        final NioEventLoopGroup acceptGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(1, acceptFactory, NioUdtProvider.BYTE_PROVIDER);
        final NioEventLoopGroup connectGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup(0, connectFactory, NioUdtProvider.BYTE_PROVIDER);

        try {
            ServerBootstrap b = new ServerBootstrap();

            b.group(acceptGroup, connectGroup)
             .channelFactory(NioUdtProvider.BYTE_ACCEPTOR)
             .option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 128)
             .handler(new LoggingHandler(LogLevel.INFO))
             .childHandler(new ChannelInitializer<UdtChannel>() {
                 @Override
                 public void initChannel(UdtChannel ch) throws Exception {
                     ChannelPipeline p = ch.pipeline();
                     p.addLast("handler", new ThumbnailerServerHandler());
                 }
             });

            // bind and start to accept incoming connections.
            b.bind(port).sync().channel().closeFuture().sync();
        } finally {
            connectGroup.shutdownGracefully();
            acceptGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        }
    }

}
```

And the thumbnail handler:

```
public class ThumbnailerServerHandler extends SimpleChannelInboundHandler<ByteBuf> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ThumbnailerServerHandler.class);
    private PipedInputStream toThumbnailer = new PipedInputStream();
    private PipedOutputStream fromClient = new PipedOutputStream(toThumbnailer);

    private static final ListeningExecutorService executor = MoreExecutors.listeningDecorator(
            Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5));

    private ListenableFuture<OutputStream> future;

    public ThumbnailerServerHandler() throws IOException {
        super(ByteBuf.class, true);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerAdded(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        future = executor.submit(() -> ThumbnailGenerator.generate(toThumbnailer));
        future.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                ctx.writeAndFlush(future.get());
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }, executor);
    }

    @Override
    public void handlerRemoved(ChannelHandlerContext ctx) throws Exception {
        this.fromClient.close();
        this.toThumbnailer.close();
    }

    @Override
    protected void channelRead0(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ByteBuf msg) throws Exception {
        int readableBytes = msg.readableBytes();
        msg.readBytes(this.fromClient, readableBytes);
    }

    @Override
    public void exceptionCaught(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Throwable cause) throws Exception {
        logger.error("Encountered error during communication", cause);
        ctx.close();
    }


}
```

Here's my simplified "thumbnailer" until I get the whole flow to work:

```
public class ThumbnailGenerator {

    public static OutputStream generate(InputStream toThumbnailer) {
        OutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try {
            IOUtils.copy(toThumbnailer, stream);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return stream;
    }

}
```

1. Is it appropriate to spin off an async task in the handlerAdded method like this? Is there a more "netty" way to do this?
2. The IOUtils.copy is supposed to and does block (due to the read on a piped input stream) until there is data available to read which is why I offloaded it into an executor pool because I can't block in the handler if I want to keep receiving bytes. However, **I've found that this *never* completes, but it does make progress**. Is that because I never encounter an EOF byte (-1)? How can I make this flow work?
3. Am I missing a construct in netty that would simplify this process? I thought about implementing it as a decoder that doesn't decode until it has the entire stream, but then I'd be loading everything into memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so it turns out I had a few misconceptions that explain why I was having trouble getting something to work.

1) Many file types don't have so-called terminal bytes. In fact, EOF bytes (most commonly -1 as it is an overflow value) is typically an implementation provided by readers to communicate to their consumers that they have reached the end of the contents. It's generally not something that exists in the file itself.

2) channelReadComplete isn't as clear cut as it sounds. channelReadComplete is called after either the max number of reads as configured in netty (defaults to 10) is met or when it has reason to believe a message has been fully sent as demonstrated by reading an empty buffer or receiving a buffer that is less than the configured chunk size.

As for why it seemed like the input stream copy was hanging, well that is because the piped input stream never produced a terminal value (this is an example of the reader-implementation of an EOF byte). PipedInputStreams only indicate EOF once the output stream driving them have been closed.

To make this implementation work, I should have upped the message count to a sufficiently high number and trusted channelReadComplete to be called after the last read that returns less than the chunk size. At which point, it'd be safe to close and reset the output stream for the next message. Closing the output stream would result in the input stream finally returning that EOF byte and everything else could continue along.